# vim: Search replace complex within each class

Tags: vim, neovim

I have many nested classes in a file. Each similar to this, but with different IDs in the ProtoMember(ID).

```
public class ApiInputs 
{
    [ProtoMember(316)]
    [JsonPropertyName("Meta")] 
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(317)]
    [JsonPropertyName("Settings")] 
    public Settings? Settings { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(318)]
    [JsonPropertyName("Weight")] 
    public Weight? Weight { get; set; }
}
```

I want to replace the IDs within each class starting each time at 1 instead of 316 (in this class). I can global replace all with "%%%%" and then use a vim command like the following to replace like I want if I only had one class. But, I need to reset the counter in each class.

```
:let i=1 | g/%%%%/s//\=i/ | let i = i+1
```

I've tried several (intermediate skill) vim commands and macros and successfully hung both of my vim editors a few times. So, how can I tell the macro or the command line to make this change within each class, restarting the counter each time.

Possible without a hack? or better to awk?

and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick would be to increment the counter inside the substitute expression using silent `execute()` and another `execute()` to check if we entered a new class to reset the counter:

```
:let i = 1 | %s/\(public class\_.\{-}\)\?ProtoMember(\zs\d\+\ze)/\=execute('if !empty(submatch(1)) | let i = 1 | endif') .. i .. execute('let i = i + 1')/
```

will give:

```
public class ApiInputs 
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    [JsonPropertyName("Meta")] 
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    [JsonPropertyName("Settings")] 
    public Settings? Settings { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    [JsonPropertyName("Weight")] 
    public Weight? Weight { get; set; }
}

public class ApiOutputs 
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    [JsonPropertyName("Meta")] 
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    [JsonPropertyName("Settings")] 
    public Settings? Settings { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    [JsonPropertyName("Weight")] 
    public Weight? Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! A nice twist on what I had, but I'm "stuck" on the other part: how do I now apply this anew within each class in the file, starting with 1 again each time. That is what I keep hanging vim on!

Comment: That would need another `execute()` to check if we entered a new class and reset the counter. I updated the answer.

Comment: Magic and a bit shorter than PowerShell to do it ...

Comment: first index started with 2 for me in nvim so did this :let i = 0 | %s/\(public class\_.\{-}\)\?ProtoMember(\zs\d\+\ze)/\=execute('if !empty(submatch(1)) | let i = 0 | endif') .. i .. execute('let i = i + 1')/